# Word for unintentional production or generation of a by-product

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb describing the production of a by-product. I want to contrast between generating heat purposefully or it being generated as a by-product of a different process.

My Example:

> Heat is either purposefully generated using a boiler or is generated
>   as a by-product of an industrial plant.

Is there a way to replace the second `generated` in the example sentence to express that it is not the main purpose of the `industrial plant` to generate heat?

Tudelus

BTW: The best way I came up with so far is replacing the first `generated` by `produced`. Is `produced` more intentional than `generated` ?

Comment: "Heat is either intentionally generated using a boiler, or as a by-product of an industrial plant."

Comment: @jimm101 your suggestion does fix my problem. So thanks for that. But it does not address my question of whether `produced` is more intentional than `generated` and whether there exists a word for producing a by-product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well! here you want to put forward an observation by contrasting between two processes by saying that one is purposeful and another is not.

1. heat by boiler is **purposeful** &
2. heat by by-product **is not**

If you want to indicate contrast between the two processes, then you can try saying;

> Heat is either purposefully generated using a boiler or is **discharged**/**released** as a by-product of an industrial plant.

There is one example from the book: [Modeling Steel Deformation in the Semi-Solid State](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=oc40DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22heat+discharge+as+a%22&source=bl&ots=L3DhtVCwlJ&sig=oLw_wQd_xxWTbeksaKmWjkE59Ow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzxP3IxN3cAhXKXCsKHUgTCAkQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22heat%20discharge%20as%20a%22&f=false) By Marcin Hojny

> In actual metal working processes, a number of effects occur in parallel, such as the metal flow, metal temperature changes, heat generation as a result of plastic deformation work, friction force work, ***heat discharge*** as a result of contact between the metal deformed and the tool, or ***heat discharge*** to the environment by radiation and convection.

And yes, your suggestion is correct on the usage of the word "produced". It sounds more intentional in the given context because you want to represent contrasting ideas. So, you can write:

> Heat is either purposefully **produced** using a boiler or is **discharged**/**released** as a by-product of an industrial plant.

Comment: Thanks that actually works for my case. I was just hoping that there was a word that would work more universally across all kinds of domains.

Comment: @oldmansaur wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

**Cogeneration**

If the heat as a secondary product was recognized as being potentially useful right from the start, this is called cogeneration. For instance, reverse osmosis desalinators require a lot less pump energy if the supply water is hot. So locating them near a power plant where they can tap into the coolant loop is very effective. Cogenerating plants are common on large ships as well.

> Cogeneration—also known as combined heat and power, distributed generation, or recycled energy—is the simultaneous production of two or more forms of energy from a single fuel source. Cogeneration power plants often operate at 50 to 70 percent higher efficiency rates than single-generation facilities.
>
> In practical terms, what cogeneration usually entails is the use of
>   what would otherwise be wasted heat (such as a manufacturing plant’s
>   exhaust) to produce additional energy benefit, such as to provide heat
>   or electricity for the building in which it is operating. Cogeneration
>   is great for the bottom line and also for the environment, as
>   recycling the waste heat saves other pollutant-spewing fossil fuels
>   from being burned.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-does-cogeneration-provide-heat-power/

Answer (score 0):

The word "purposefully" is problematic in this context as well so something like the below is the best version I can see:

"Heat is either deliberately generated, i.e. using a boiler, or is a captured by-product from an industrial plant."

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I don't quite see how purposefully is problematic, although I do like `deliberately` better.

Comment: @oldmansaur This is probably an idiomatic thing but I've always had "purposeful" described to me as a matter of personal intentions rather than a characteristic that can be applied to mechanistic systems in any way.

Comment: Also the by-product would still be a by-product even if it were not captured. In my case the by-product is just vented and I want to say that it is being generated and not used. So `captured` is maybe not the correct word for my case.

Comment: @oldmansaur Yes but you wouldn't be using the by-product if you had not captured it, it would therefore not be a heat source for the system but only a by-product of an industrial plant.